# How to print info from mysql db

Tags: mysql

I need help with php 
print info from mysql db

I wanna print in a table from db info I have

```
Product_Name
Product_Description
Product_Description2
```

I need to know what code to write

in db I have description of products so I need to print for each product this description with 

{
echo Product_Name ... etc.. ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please try to make you questions specifically about code.  For example, are you asking for the SQL to show the three fields you listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could try something like the following.

**Edit:** *taken into account you already have a connection in config.php*

In *config.php* make sure you have the following.

```
<?php 
    $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","database");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
?>
```

And then on the page where you want to display the results add.

```
 <?php

    include_once("config.php"); //Can be removed if already added.

    $query = "SELECT Product_Name, Product_Description, Product_Description2 FROM tablename";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

      echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Product_Description</th><th>Product_Description2</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Product_Name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Product_Description'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Product_Description2'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

**Edit2:** *Get product info by id*

If you want to get a product by ID Try changing the query to.

```
"SELECT Product_Name, Product_Description, Product_Description2 FROM tablename WHERE Product_id = '$id'";
```

Comment: in header I already a connection added it calls the ./config.php include_once("config.php");

Comment: in header I already a connection added

Comment: i want to get info for a id - I have about 100 products on database